# Proving the equation of positive definite submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices, schur-complement

For $n \ge 2$, $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are $n \times n$ positive definite matrices.  Now, for a scalar $\alpha > 0$ and $(n-1)$-dimensional column vector $\beta$ and $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ $\Delta$ matrix.

Given that

$$
  A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta^T \\\ \beta & \Delta \end{bmatrix}
$$

$\tilde{A}$ is the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ submatrix, and I would like to prove the following holds,

$$
  \tilde{A}^{-1} = \Delta - \dfrac{\beta\beta^T}{\alpha}
$$

I have tried to decompose the $A^{-1}$ to something like

$$
    \begin{align*}
       \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta^T \\\ \beta & \Delta \end{bmatrix}^{-1} & = 
       \begin{bmatrix} I & O \\\ \beta/\alpha & I \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta^T \\\ O & \Delta - \beta\beta^T/\alpha \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \\\
    \end{align*}
$$

Yet, I am not sure where to keep going at this point, what should I focus on for this moment?

Comment: The [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) Wikipedia page has a proof of how to take an inverse of a block matrix like yours.

Comment: Thank you, this page is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b^T\\ b & \tilde A\end{bmatrix}$. Now use the block multiplication to have this two equations:

$$b\beta^T + \tilde A \Delta = I$$ and $$\alpha b + \tilde A \beta = 0.$$

Now multiply the first equality with $\alpha$ and the second equality with $\beta^T$ and take the difference of two equations to have:

$$\tilde A \left(\alpha \Delta - \beta \beta^T\right) = \alpha I.$$

Comment: Thank you!! This is what I need, this is simpler than what I was trying. Yet, I noticed that you wrote $\tilde{A}(\alpha\Delta - \beta\beta^T) = I$, after followed your idea, I think $I$ should be replace with $\alpha$.

Comment: Yes $\alpha I$ indeed